# Почему — целью, а не цель?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Почему мы говорим «имеющий целью», а не — «имеющий цель»?

Например: «Благотворительный — имеющий целью оказание материальной помощи нуждающимся».

Comment: Куда делся (благотворительный) "фонд"?

Comment: Интересно, а как быть с выражениями  "имеющий ценность ", "имеющий смысл"?(В.П ) Как оценят на экзамене, если написать -"имеющий ценностью " или "имеющий смыслом". Боюсь,что не оценят...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мы говорим одно и другое в разных ситуациях. "*Имеющий цель*" - буквальное выражение, применимое к *субъекту* (теннисист, *имеющий цель* победить на "Уимблдоне"). Выражение же "*имеющий целью*" идиоматично и синонимично страд. причастию "**предназначенный**" (как в случае с "фондом"), фонду как бы "придали цель" извне - как пассивной сущности, которая не ставит перед собой "целей". Для фонда возможен и контекст, когда он понимается как коллектив, ставящий перед собой *конкретную* цель (скорее всего, фонд, буквально "имеющий цель", окажется в именительном падеже).

**P.S.** Книжный пример:

> *...[вожак стаи] выполняет особый маневр, **имеющий целью** отрезать от стаи одного определенного скворца...* (К истокам человеческой
> коммуникации, Ю. Монич, 2018)

Здесь присутствуют и носитель цели (скворец - вожак стаи, "**имеющий цель**"), и средство осуществления той же цели (маневр, "**имеющий целью**"). Т. е. противопоставляемые два выражения различаются своей принадлежностью **носителю** цели, либо **средству** её достижения.

Answer (score 3):

> Благотворительный — имеющий целью оказание материальной помощи нуждающимся.

Достаточно изменить порядок слов — *имеющий оказание материальной помощи целью*, — чтобы и такой вариант признать вполне корректным. В одном случае (*имеющий цель*) имеется в виду наличие некой цели, а в другом — она ясно обозначена и такой ***целью является оказание*** помощи людям.